# Installed Ruby version are different in macOS and Bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm not using RVM but brew to install and update Ruby and Gem version up-to-date. But when I was trying `bundle install`, I got an error showed that the Ruby version requirement does not conform.

I added `ruby '2.1.9'` to the Gemfile and did some check:

```
(●—●) ↪ bundle platform                                                                                
Your platform is: universal.x86_64-darwin16

Your app has gems that work on these platforms:
* ruby

Your Gemfile specifies a Ruby version requirement:
* ruby 2.1.9

Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.9
(●—●) ↪ ruby -v                                                                                         
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
(●—●) ↪ gem -v                                                                                         
2.6.11
```

I found that there is a lower version Ruby in my project.

`/Users/veck/Desktop/Project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0`

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I successfully did `bundle install` with following action:

`gem install bundler`

After this installation, my vendor/bundle/ruby has one more version `2.4.0`. Then I retry `bundle install` and all works fine.

**Note**: But 2.0.0 version of ruby still stay in vendor/bundle.